# Disable Form Submit until Fields have been validated using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, form-submit

I have modified this script http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xtPhk/1/ to submit a form. 
The goal is to disable submit button until all form fields have been validated. 
This works fine the first time but since, my form does not have a action jquery handles the submit as well.

So after I submit the form, the submit button does not get disabled. I have to refresh the page in order for it to get disabled.

What I am trying to do is, after every post.. the submit button should get disabled, without refreshing the page.

Is this possible ?

It does work if my form has a action page. but I dont want that

Form Submit:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#paForm").submit(sendForm)
    });

   function sendForm() {
      $.post('pa_submit.cfm',$("#paForm").serialize(),function(data,status){
    $("#result").html(data)
});// end of submit 
$( '#paForm' ).each(function(){
      this.reset(); // end of reset 
  });
return false
  }
```

Disable Submit Button until all fields have been validated

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $form = $('#paForm'); // cache
       $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); // disable submit btn
      $form.find(':input').change(function() { // monitor all inputs for changes
    var disable = false;
       $form.find(':input').not('[type="submit"]').each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
            if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
            disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
           }
        });
         $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',disable);
      });
    });
```

I am using a jquery function to post my values to a database. My form does not have a action.

http://jsfiddle.net/bC6GF/

Here is the jsfiddle page, which shows my issue.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for you to read, and others to help you with.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, can you not use a button rather than a submit button and use ajax on button click to post the data into the database?

Comment: I put the code in JSfiddle, shows my issue.
And my issue is I am unable to use Ajax calls in Coldfusion, sadly this is not php :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not disable the button after submit?

You already have the submission function in place:

```
function sendForm() {
 $.post('pa_submit.cfm',$("#paForm").serialize(),function(data,status){
  $("#result").html(data)
 });// end of submit 
 $( '#paForm' ).each(function(){
  this.reset(); // end of reset 
 });
 return false;
}
```

Extend with a call to the submit button to disable it:

```
function sendForm() {
 $.post('pa_submit.cfm',$("#paForm").serialize(),function(data,status){
  $("#result").html(data)
 });// end of submit 
 $( '#paForm' ).each(function(){
  this.reset(); // end of reset 
 });
 $("#paForm").find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); 
 return false;
}
```

That should disable the button after each submit.

Unrelated but something you may want to look into are the jQuery [JavaScript Style Guides](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/) and cleanup some of your code.

Comment: Thank you it worked.
And yes i am doing my best to clean up the code